# stripped down version of jQuery for ajax/json functionality

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I like AJAX/JSON features of jQuery but the library is very big for blackberry phone development. Has anyone pulled out or developed a stand alone AJAX/JSON library similar to jQuery's?  I know that a mobile version of jQuery is coming, but this looks like it is more directed at GUI for iPhone. I also tried XUI, but have been getting JavaScript errors when running in IE7.

Comment: The production version of jquery is minified , did you try that.They have dev version and production version.

Comment: I always use minified version. Even this is almost 80kb.  Even if the code is cached on second call, the blackberry seems to spend alot of time parsing js code on every load.

Comment: one more way might be , take the dev version and go through the code and take the functionalities only required for you , i don't much about PDA development , but giving my thoughts.

Comment: Well, it's minified, but it's still huge.  I suggest looking into the [Jo Framework](http://joapp.com/), about which I've heard good things from [a notable, influential source](http://twitter.com/brianleroux).

Comment: jquery does not look like it can unbundle easily.  BTW I found the problem with XUI library. I was using blackberry version which assumes you are using a BB device which makes it difficult to test with IE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is slightly tricky to accomplish. As lonesomeday has mentioned, that is one way. The other way is to write a small piece of code which uses all the functions you need from jQuery e.g. a dummy function with ajax calls and json etc.

Then put everything into a single JS file and run it through [Google's Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) with Advanced Optimization.

Comment: This is a really nice suggestion! This can work in all sorts of places as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the source files for jQuery [on GitHub](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src/).  It looks to me like you will need the following files to do AJAX, which you can probably compile and minify:

- core.js
- support.js
- ajax.js
- data.js
- event.js

I haven't properly tested this yet, but it seems plausible that it should work.  Whether it will actually be a significant performance benefit, I don't know.

**Edit** I've used the [Google Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) to compile all these and minify them.  The file can be seen [on that site](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/code/jscd5cd4f911a596a0e30af1ef0a0257bca/jquery.ajax.js).  It seems to work as far as I can tell, for a simple `$.ajax` call.  Note that, as Nick says, all kinds of filtering functionality could be missing.  Keep your usage of this simple and use at your own risk.  Better, use a dedicated AJAX library.

Comment: If you want the selector engine you'll need more than this, Sizzle itself and `sizzle-jquery.js` for example.